# JSON Web Token no longer has 'decode' attribute despite no changes

Tags: python, django, jwt, twilio, twilio-api

I have a function which provides a token for a user so they can access a video chat room using the Twilio Video API. Following their docs, we decode a JSON Web Token with the following code to give us their token:

```py
token = AccessToken(ACCOUNT_SID, API_KEY, API_SECRET, identity=f'{request.user.email}')
token.add_grant(VideoGrant(room='My Room'))
context = {
    'token': token.to_jwt().decode()
}
```

This worked perfectly locally, and upon pushing it to live servers, continued to work there without fault. However, a few pushes later, with no changes to this code, and this error (below) has suddenly occurred. This also comes at the same time as another error, which is an ascii encoding error, which I believe may be linked.

It's strange that although no changes have been made to this token object, or the function, that we suddenly encounter this error with decoding this token. If anyone has any pointers, would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot from user]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyJWT changed the return type of `jwt.encode` from `bytes` to `str`: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#jwt-encode-return-type

Solution is to either downgrade/pin the `PyJWT` package to `1.7.1` or remove the call to `decode`

```
context = {
    'token': token.to_jwt()
}
```

Comment: That was the fix for production, thanks! Strangely, production didn't complain installing `PyJWT 2.0` despite Twilio requiring `1.7.1`. Dev servers didn't let the incompatibility install, hence the error on one side